# Google Classroom Share button: I can't select a course

Tags: google-classroom

I put a Classroom Share Button in my Angular web app.
It works for teachers but not for students.

When a student click the Share button and select a course, Google Classroom popup says "Select a course with assignment tasks" (in spite of student ha assigned courseworks).

What can be the cause?
I forgot some scope?
Teacher or student needs to configure something in Classroom?
Or something else?

Thank you.

Comment: What happens if the student follows the steps throughout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED.
It's a strange behaviour (a bug?) of Google Classroom: courseworks must have a deadline.

Share popup permits to select only courses with a deadline.